# need perl one liner to remove blank lines from beginning of file

Tags: perl

I have the following script to strip a license region from a file,
but I am left with a blank line at the beginning.

```
perl -pi~ -ne 'if (/#region License/../#endregion/) {$_ = "" if ($. == 1 || $. == 2)}' $i
```

Comment: The `-n` switch is ignored if you also provide the `-p` switch.

Comment: What does your file look like? What you have written will eliminate lines between the two markers *if* they happen to be on the first or second lines of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -i~ -ne'
    next if /#region License/../#endregion/;
    next if !$body && /^\s+\z/;
    ++$body;
    print;
' "$i"
```

Feel free to remove the line breaks, although it will work with them. They're there for readability.

Comment: Thanks! I needed to run it twice in order to get rid of the blank line.

Comment: Yeah. I am still happy because the second time around fixed it. I am running perl in Git shell on windows, so there might be quirks to how it runs.  Thanks again!